# Determine if UPDATE or INSERT when using ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using a mysqli/php query that looks like this:

```
$query = "
INSERT INTO table (unique_key, column_1, column_2) 
VALUES (?,?,?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
value_1 = ?, value_2 = ?";
if ($statement = $mysqli->prepare($query))
{
    $statement->bind_param("iiiii", $unique_key, $value_1, $value_2, $value_1, $value_2);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->close();
}
```

How do I tell if the query executed an UPDATE or an INSERT?

Comment: change this  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
column_1 = ?, column_2 = ?";

Answer (score 16):

You can use [`mysqli_affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) and check return value. From [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html):

> For `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statements, the affected-rows
> value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an
> existing row is updated, and 0 if an existing row is set to its
> current values.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this one myself:

```
$flag = $statement->insert_id;
```

If `$flag > 0` then it was an insert, otherwise it was an update.

Comment: This returns the id both on update and insert. it only returns 0 If on update nothing changed.

Answer (score -1):

The difference between INSERT AND UPDATE is a UNIQUE KEY. You can define so much UNIQUE KEY YOU want. if one key has a duplication it goes to the UPDATE.

if you have a "normal" INSERT INTO" wich give you an error for duplicate key error the the ON DUPLICATE works

here a sample

**the table**

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> show create table dup;

+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| dup   | CREATE TABLE `dup` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

**Insert one row**

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> insert into dup (id,a) VALUES(1,5);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)
```

*see the table**

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> select * from dup;
+----+------+
| id | a    |
+----+------+
|  1 |    5 |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

**insert the same again = error**

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> insert into dup (id,a) VALUES(1,5);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
MariaDB [yourschema]>
```

**INSERT with ON DUPLICATE KEY**

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> insert into dup (id,a) VALUES(1,5) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a=a+VALUES(a);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

**see table again - it adds field a**

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> select * from dup;
+----+------+
| id | a    |
+----+------+
|  1 |   10 |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [yourschema]>
```

**USAGE**

the correct usage of INSERT INTO .... ON DUPLICATE KEY is:

```
INSERT INTO table (unique_key, column_1, column_2) 
VALUES (?,?,?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
value_1 = VALUES(column_1), value_2 = VALUES(column_2)";
```

the you only use 3 arg for prepare and its also possible to insert more rows

```
INSERT INTO table (unique_key, column_1, column_2) 
VALUES (?,?,?),(?,?,?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
value_1 = VALUES(column_1), value_2 = VALUES(column_2)";
```

Comment: That's a good point but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @revo - i have a a sample in my answer

Comment: Yet it doesn't answer the question!

Comment: So much effort to write, so much effort to read, only to find out it's all irelevant to the question :/